# How to mark a non HTTP/s schema URL as clickable on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, support, hyperlinks

How to mark a non HTTP/s schema URL as clickable on Stack Exchange sites?

For example, some Chrome setting has the following URL: chrome://settings/syncSetup

Tried several ways to mark it as URL but failed:

1. chrome://settings/syncSetup
2. chrome://settings/syncSetup

* Any idea how to make those URLs clickable?